# UNIX: How would I grep in a script using a variable as a search parameter for a file?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

Before I Start, this isn't exactly how it seems and I did search the web for a while before coming here. Basically I have a script where the user passes in a string and stores it in a variable. I then have to take that word and search for all the subwords that could be made from it in a dictionary file. The problem I am having is I need to make sure the words are at least 4 characters long. I do not have the best grasp on regular expressions. I'm aware of the techniques you can use just logically can't piece it together sometimes. I will show you the line of code and explain my reasoning behind why I think it should be this way. Then, could someone correct me on my logic? I am not looking for someone to send me the working line of code but perhaps correct my logic so I can understand better and derive the answer on my own.

```
words=$(grep -iE '(["$text"]{4,})' /usr/dict/words)
echo "$words"
```

For example if I pass in string college I should get output like
cell
cello
clee 
cleg
etc.....

I am storing the command in another variable to echo. I am not sure why exactly, It just seems from what I saw online most people were rather fond of this. Using grep with -i for ignore case and -E for regular expression or (egrep) I believe the expression needs to be enclosed in single quote parenthesis for expressions. $text is the variable I stored the users input in. I know $ usually signifies the ending in and [] is a range and "" makes it read the variable rather than print what is there. Then {4,} meaning four or more characters. then the last part is the path to the file. Any input would be appreciated and again, I do not like being spoon fed answers it's an easy way to learn nothing. I would just like corrections on my logic if all possible. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: one issue is that your $text won't expand inside single quotes.  You should close the single quote, put the variable and then reopen the single quote e.g. 'stuff'"$text"'stuff'

Comment: You should also quote the variable expansion: `'(["'"$text"'"]{4,})'`

Comment: Since you're not using a capturing group or `?, *, +` etc. modifiers on your overall expression I believe you can also drop the parentheses: `'['"$text"']{4,}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "subwords" you mean permutations of its letters, then your command is fine except for the quotes. Unfortunately you have to do it like this:

```
words=$(grep -iE '(['"$text"']{4,})' /usr/dict/words)
```

This way you pass to `grep` the single quoted string so that the shell doesn't interpret its special symbols. But at the same time you have to expand your `$text` var, thus you have to make a gap inside your single-quoted string, and in that gap place your variable in double quotes.

Hope I didn't spoil it for you.

Comment: Based off what you said I was able to derive an answer with the addition of  ^  so  '^(['"$text"']{4,}' Thank you very much for your help I appreciate it. However, would you be able to explain to me what the ^ does I know in a range it means not so like [^abc] not abc but what did it mean in this instance? when coded like your suggestion above it prints all words in the dictionary with the added ^ when passing in a word like college it prints words like cell color colony coll etc...

Comment: ```^```, if not within a range (```[]```), means *beginning of the string* which in your case means "match the string that starts with any of the letters of c,o,l,e,d,g". Check this awesome cheat sheet http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/